# php login authentification token_id and login script found on the net - secure?

Tags: php, authentication

While making my new site i needed new login script, so i can feel comfortable with my data. I made such scripts earlier, but who knew how secure they were. Hoping to find some anwer on the web i found such a tutorial that calls itself 'super secure login script'. You can find it in this [link](http://www.newthinktank.com/2011/01/web-design-and-programming-pt-21-secure-login-script)

I wonder how secure it really is, and what kind of threats is it vulnerable.

I also found in code lines like this:

```
// Create Second Token
$tokenId = rand(10000, 9999999);
$query2 = “update users set tokenid = $tokenId where userid = ‘$_SESSION[userid]‘”;
$result2 = mysql_query ($query2);
$_SESSION['token_id'] = $tokenId;
```

How should it work? What is it preventing from? Should i compare $_SESSION['token_id'] with something later or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted is simply creating a random number, then storing it on the user record in the users database table, then storing it in the session.
Based on the link provided, the token or random number doesn't actually get used for anything at all. You'll have to ask the developer for the meaning of that.

I wouldn't recommend the login script you linked to for these reasons:

1) The way it escapes user input to avoid SQL Injection

Here is the function that is used:

```
function escape_data ($data) {

 // Check for mysql_real_escape_string() support.

 // This function escapes characters that could be used for sql injection

 if (function_exists(‘mysql_real_escape_string’)) {

 global $dbc; // Need the connection.

 $data = mysql_real_escape_string (trim($data), $dbc);

 $data = strip_tags($data);

 } else {

 $data = mysql_escape_string (trim($data));

 $data = strip_tags($data);

 }

 // Return the escaped value. 

 return $data;

 } // End of function.
```

The above function has some problems. The biggest being that if it finds that `mysql_real_escape_string()` does not exist, it falls back to `mysql_escape_string()`. You should never fall back to mysql_escape_string(). If mysql_real_escape_string() is not available and you're relying on it to avoid SQL Injection, your application should stop.
The other problem with this is it is uses `strip_tags()`. Escaping for SQL Injection and escaping/encoding for XSS are two different things and shouldn't be combined into one.

I suggest using MySQLi prepared statements or PDO parameterised queries instead of this function, to avoid SQL Injection.

To avoid XSS, use `htmlentities()` whenever content from the database (or direct user input) is printed out which originated from user input.

2) This is bad practice

```
$_SESSION[userid] // this should have single quotes, making it $_SESSION['userid']
```

3) PHP logic and HTML are mixed in together, no effort is made to separate them.

4) CAPTCHA on the login form. This is just going to make users unhappy. Usually there is no need for a CAPTCHA on a login form.

**Edit - here I've responded to some of your points in the comments.**

**Author's intention for token**

It's anyone's guess really but perhaps the random number was meant to be used in a password reset link.
For that sort of thing, hashing the random number/string is usually done rather than keeping a short random number. Also mt_rand() is better than rand().

**Using a single function for SQLi escaping and XSS prevention**

This is a bad idea because they are two very different things. Escaping for SQLi is done inbound to the database, XSS prevention should be done outbound if you see what I mean.

When storing data in the database, it is usually best stored in raw form rather than having it had strip_tags() or htmlentities(). What if at some point you want to allow HTML to be entered into the database for any reason?

The XSS prevention should be done as the data comes out of the database and onto the page or where ever it goes to. What if you want to output the data to another medium other than HTML, like XML or to a web service, and you've already processed it for HTML.
A single function for both XSS and SQLi doesn't make the code cleaner, it applies processes to data that don't need to be applied at that time.

Look at any popular framework such as Zend, or CMS such as WordPress, Joomla etc. None of them use a single function for both SQLi and XSS.

**Mixing PHP and HTML**

Yes you're right it isn't going to affect security but it just looks terrible. It is hard to read, hard to maintain, hard to extend and update, and definately remains a reason I would not recommend it.

**Quotes in `$_SESSION['userid']`**

Using `$_SESSION[userid]` inside a query to solve the problem of the query breaking due to quotes, shows lack of knowledge/experience.

You can use quotes, you just need to concatenate the variable into the query like

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE something = '" . $_SESSION['something'] . '";
```

Of course you need to escape for SQLi (preferable using parameterised queries) if you're unsure of the contents of the variable.

**CAPTCHA**

CAPTCHA is great when used in the right places. A login form like this is not one of them. You could use a CAPTCHA after X failed attempts (as Google do), but not like this where it is required all of the time.
There are other ways of dealing with brute force login attempts, several answers here on SO.

Another point that I didn't mention is the password hashing. That is using SHA1 with no salt, which is not very strong. I would use SHA256 or higher and use a salt for passwords.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand code in this link so the code i attached to my previous post was quite useless so i asked maybe someone can understand intentions of author. Or for example there is $_SESSION['token_id'] special variable that session uses for some strange purposes.

Comment: I agree with your 1 answer - without mysql_real_escape_string everything should stop, but i dont see why mixing in one function sql ijection remedy and xss remedy is bad. I guess it's good idea to have each data filtred by one complex function that prevents both, xss and mysql injection threats depending on type of input data. It makes code much more clean. 2) can you write ' signs to limit variable name in mysql query? I cant it results an error. So "SELECT data FROM table WHERE id=$_SESSION['id']" would give me an error message.

Comment: 3) i guess mixing php is html is just a good look issue, not a safety threat. 4) i do not like captcha also. I guess nobody likes it. But it's quite good idea to prevent some bots of brutal login attempts one by one.

Comment: @Kalreg I've edited the answer and responded to your points there, rather than trying to squeeze it into a comment.

Comment: After all I have to admit you are right in all your answers. :) I'm glad being here on stack overflow with such people like you. Please give me a few answers: Is using htmlentites would make me free from xss threats? Is mysql_real_escape_string going to make me free from mysql injection threat? What is "salt" for passwords?

Comment: If you pass the user supplied content through htmlentities() as it is printed onto the page then it will protect you from XSS. Lookup Parameterised Queries (or Prepared Statements), these are preferable to avoid SQLi. `mysql_real_escape_string()` will work too (for strings), but there have been bugs in it in the past. Password salting is to add a string (could be random or related to the user) to the password before it gets hashed. It makes the hash harder to reverse. See http://docs.moodle.org/22/en/Password_salting